# mysql - union tables by unique field

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables with the same structure:

```
id name
1 Merry
2 Mike

and

id name
1 Mike
2 Alis
```

I need to union second table to first with keeping unique names, so that result is:

```
id name
1 Merry
2 Mike
3 Alis
```

Is it possible to do this with MySQL query, without using php script?

Comment: Ehmmm, what id do you want to have for mike..?
You can't go for random luck, cause in t1 he has 2 and in t2 he has 1

Comment: id should be unique. No other requirements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a join (set multiplication), this is a union (set addition).

```
SELECT  @r := @r + 1 AS id, name
FROM    (
        SELECT  @r := 0
        ) vars,
        (
        SELECT  name
        FROM    table1
        UNION
        SELECT  name
        FROM    table2
        ) q
```

Comment: Ah nice one, you figured he needs some new sequence as ID

Comment: where can i read about "@r := @r + 1" syntax? never saw it before

Comment: This is great, just be sure you're running MySQL 5.0 or greater, otherwise you won't have User Defined Variables.

Answer (score 2):

This will select all names from table1 and combine those with all the names from table2 which are not in table1.

```
(
select * 
from table1        
)
union
(        
select * 
from table2 t2 
left join table1 t1 on t2.name = t1.name 
where t1.id is null
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.name
  FROM TABLE_A a
UNION
SELECT b.id,
       b.name
  FROM TABLE_B b
```

UNION will remove duplicates.

Comment: yep, i just figured that in my case i can just delete id, then UNION tables and than add new id. it is easy way.

Comment: Using Qiao's sample data, you'll get two Mikes in the result set, with ids 1 and 2. In order for UNION to remove duplicates, the entire row must be identical.

Answer (score 0):

*As commented, it all depends on what your 'id' means, cause in the example, it means nothing.*

```
SELECT DISTINCT(name) FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON something
```

if you only want the names

```
SELECT SUM(something), name FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON something GROUP BY name
```

if you want to do some group by

```
SELECT DISTINCT(name) FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

if the id's are the same

Comment: your queries only return the duplicate names.  The desired result is a non-redundant union.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(t1.name,t2.name) FROM
mytable t1 LEFT JOIN mytable t2 ON (t1.name=t2.name);
```

will get you a list of unique names from the 2 tables.  If you want them to get new ids (like Alis does in your desired results), that's something else and requires the answers to a couple of questions:

- do any of the names need to maintain their previous id.  And if they do, which table's id should be preferred?
- why do you have 2 tables with the same structure? ie what are you trying to accomplish when you generate the unique name list?